# Python: achar produto do maior valor de cada lista da matriz

Tags: python, matriz

Caros Senhores(as),
já pesquisei muito antes de postar minha dúvida. 
Já estou até desanimado.

Trata-se de um trabalho da universidade. Se puderem me dar uma dica, eu agradeço.

O exercício pede:
"(c) Qual é o produto dos maiores valores de cada uma das linhas;"

Abaixo está o código... Obrigado.

```
import random

#cria matriz
matriz = []
#usuário digita a Qtd de linhas e colunas desejadas;
m = int(input("Informe a qtd de linhas desejadas na Matriz: "))
n = int(input("Informe a qtd de colunas desejadas na Matriz: "))
#usuário define o intervalo para geração automática de valores.
a = int(input("Defina o início do intervalo para geração aleatória: "))
b = int(input("Defina o fim do intervalo para geração aleatória: "))

max = None  # Armazena o maior valor
posicao = (0, 0)  # Armazena a posição do maior valor


for i in range(1, m+1):
    linha = []
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        x = float(random.uniform(a, b)) #gera números aleatórios dentro do intervalo definido
        if max is None or x > max:
            max = x
            posicao = (i, j)

        linha.append(x)
        matriz.append(linha)


print("----------------------------")
print("Respostas das alternativas")
print("----------------------------")
print("(A) A matriz gerada aleatoriamente é: ", matriz)
print("(B) O maior valor está na posição {} e vale {}".format(posicao, max))
print("(C) ainda não consegui resolver")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do Isac, é possível também calcular o produto dos maiores números de cada linha da matriz utilizando uma combinação das funções `max`, que obtém o maior valor de um iterável, `map`, que aplica uma função sobre um iterável e `reduce`, que reduz um iterável para um escalar, com base em uma função. Neste caso, fazemos `map(max, matrix)` para obter um iterável com todos os maiores valores de cada linha da matriz e calculamos o produto destes com a função `reduce`:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

result = reduce(mul, map(max, matrix), 1)

print("Resultado:", result)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/eALRp4https://repl.it/@acwoss/OvercookedStarchyTechnicians) | Repl.it</sup>

O código praticamente é o equivalente ao apresentado pelo Isac:

```
produto = 1
for linha in matriz:
    produto *= max(linha)
```

Mas é bom sempre conhecer as alternativas e pode acontecer de ser interessante aplicar esta solução funcional.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson! :)

Comment: Nem me lembrei do `reduce`. Diria que fica mais pythonico :)

Comment: @isac, não necessariamente. Com o `reduce` a solução fica mais próxima do paradigma funcional, o que pode trazer vantagens em alguns projetos, porém, de certa forma, prejudica a legibilidade. O laço `for` fica muito mais fácil de ler e entender o que é feito. Para uma solução simples como essa, eu optaria pela legibilidade do `for` mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Para calcular o maior valor de cada linha pode usar a [função nativa `max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max). Ela tanto pode receber os vários valores ou uma lista com os valores:

```
>>> max(1,2,3)
3
>>> max([3,5,1,6,2])
6
```

Com esta função o calculo do produto dos maiores valores de cada linha passa a ser:

```
produto = 1
for linha in matriz:
    produto *= max(linha)
```

No entanto o seu código não tinha a adição da linha à matriz no sitio certo devido à indentação. Para alem disso se pretende adicionar `m` linhas é indiferente se vai de `1` a `m` ou de `0` a `m-1` e por isso torna-se mais fácil utilizar `range(m)` ao invés de `range(1, m+1)`.

Reescreva assim a leitura da matriz para:

```
for i in range(m): # range(m) em vez de range(1, m+1)
    linha = []
    for j in range(n): # aqui também range simplificado
        x = float(random.uniform(a, b)) #gera números aleatórios dentro do intervalo definido
        linha.append(x)

    matriz.append(linha) # não ao mesmo nivel do linha.append(x)
```

Com esta simplificação para o calculo do máximo deixou de haver necessidade de utilizar as `max` e `posicao` que tinha. Deixo no entanto um alerta importante no sentido de não usar nomes que já existam em funções nativas como `max` pois acaba por lhe dar erros estranhos quando precisar de usar as mesmas.

Pode também combinar o calculo do produto com o achar do maior e a sua posição utilizando a função [`index`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), que lhe permite achar a posição de um elemento na lista:

```
produto = 1
maior = max([max(linha) for linha in matriz]) # achar o maior

for posicao, linha in enumerate(matriz):
    produto *= max(linha)
    if maior in linha: # se o maior está nesta linha
        posicao_maior = (posicao, linha.index(maior)) # guardar a sua posição
```

E com tão pouco código responde às três perguntas solicitadas.

[Veja o seu funcionamento no Ideone](https://ideone.com/P479FW)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Vou verificar   :)

Comment: Isac, agradeço muito. Você me ajudou muito! Eu consegui resolver as questões com sua ajuda. Desejo uma boa noite! :)

Comment: @WilsonJunior Fico contente de ter ajudado. Qualquer questão que tenha é só colocar.